# pluploader get full path from local file?

Tags: jquery, file-upload, plupload

I am using pluploader, it works fine. But I want to use jcrop to crop the image before I save it on server.

So, I need to know the local path of the file to show it on browser.

There is a way to get the local name eg c:\images\photo10.jpg before I upload it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For security reasons, I don't think it's possible as stated here: http://www.plupload.com/punbb/viewtopic.php?id=51

But, you can use the resize option to resize images before uploading. If it doesn't solve your problem, maybe it helps you to find a way.